# SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED sphinx

Tags: sphinx

I have the following in my index *this is test*, and I want to be able to search for "this test is". 
In other words, I'm looking for exact match with no regards to the words position.

Is this true?

```
$cl->SetMatchMode( SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED);
$result = $cl->Query( '"this test is"~3', $index  );
```

If it is true then is the number after the `~` should be the count of the words to get the exact match search with no regards to the positions?

I have tested the result and it looks good but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of the proximity operator looks fine to me.